# printing different headers for each types of file

Tags: php, apache, header

I'm looking for an example how printing different headers for each types of file.

for example:

```
set the foo:baa in headers .png files.
set the foo:baa2 in headers .txt files
```

.
etc..

It is possible using apache/.htaccess or with some .config file?
I hope this is clear. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: No, this is not clear.  What is `foo:baa`?

Comment: an example of headers for set in this page.
as in PHP: header('foo:baa')

Comment: Agreed. Are you printing to a page? Or are you referring to setting a header for a request? Are you trying to get the appropriate header for the files?

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to set the appropriate header for the files.
for .png files header type ,.txt orther header type.. etc.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>  
    <Files "*.txt">  
        Header set Header-name "header content"
    </Files>  
</IfModule>
```

?

Comment: why does not works? `<IfModule mod_headers.c>   

   <filesMatch "\.(foo|baa)$">

        Header set Content-Type "text/plain" 

  </filesMatch>  

</IfModule> 

`

Comment: Do you have mod_headers module enabled in your Apache?